# autocomplete doesn't display initial value when used with [displayWith]

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I have an edit form that displays the value of the employee object in different form field that I am editing. There are some autocomplete fields on the form that are bound to objects. One of them is an address field. I am using `displayWith` to show complete address as string in the autocomplete input field. It is not displaying the value in the input filed of the autocomplete when the form loads.

Here's the code:

```
legalAddress: FormControl;

  this.legalAddress = new FormControl(
      this.data.addresses
        ? this._address.getAddressByType(this.data.addresses, AddressType.Legal)
        : '',
    );

<mat-form-field class="address-autocomplete">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Legal Address" aria-label="legaladdress" matInput [formControl]="legalAddress"
    [matAutocomplete]="lglAddress">
  <mat-error *ngIf="legalAddress.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
  <mat-autocomplete #lglAddress="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="addressToString">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let address of legalAddresses | async" [value]="address">
      {{ address | addressToString }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I was passing string in new FormControl('abc...'), whereas I should have been passing the address object itself.

```
  this.legalAddress = new FormControl(this.data.legalAddress);
```